# Can courts absolutely not grant bail or reduce sentences under the NDPS Act?

Tags: criminal-law, india, drugs, bail

The [Narcotic Drugs and Psychotropic Substances Act, 1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcotic_Drugs_and_Psychotropic_Substances_Act,_1985) (NDPS Act) states the following

> No suspension, remission or commutation in any sentence awarded under this Act.—Notwithstanding anything contained in the Code of Criminal Procedure, 1973 (2 of 1974) or any other law for the time being in force but subject to the provisions of section 33, no sentence awarded under this Act (other than section 27) shall be suspended or remitted or commuted.]

it further states that

> Notwithstanding anything contained in the Code of Criminal Procedure, 1973 (2 of 1974)—
> (a) every offence punishable under this Act shall be cognizable;
> (b) no person accused of an offence punishable for 2[offences under section 19 or section 24 or section 27A and also for offences involving commercial quantity] shall be released on bail or on his own bond unless—
> (i) the Public Prosecutor has been given an opportunity to oppose the application for such release, and
> (ii) where the Public Prosecutor opposes the application, the court is satisfied that there are reasonable grounds for believing that he is not guilty of such offence and that he is not likely to commit any offence while on bail.
> (2) The limitations on granting of bail specified in clause (b) of sub-section (1) are in addition to the limitations under the Code of Criminal Procedure, 1973 (2 of 1974) or any other law for the time being in force, on granting of bail.]

Are these restrictions absolute and can a court absolutely not grant bail except for those cases or reduce a sentance?

Comment: Just as a reminder, it is helpful to people trying to search for posts on an issue later on to have more than a country tag for a question.